# Improve the quality of my AR image - ARCore Android

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I have an AR video camera in my app but the projected AR image is with low quality. Is there any way to improve the quality ? Im not talking about the dimension in dp like height and width but the actual quality of the image.Also Im using a ViewRenderable in order to visualize. Im adding a screenshot so you can see the quality. Please ignore the red arrows. Thanks in advance !

[image]